# Magento 1.9 checkout not finishing after selecting payment

Tags: magento, checkout

Recently i updated a Magento 1.7 installation to Magento 1.9, after that my checkout is not completing.

First i had the problem that the checkout would not go further than selecting the shipping method. I added:

```html
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

to `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`and then i could proceed to selecting the payment method.

After selecting a payment method i click on `proceed` and i see the order details but when i click on `proceed` on the latest step, Magento does not do anything.

When i look to the XHR requests i see the following call when i click on place order:

http://www.mdaccept.com/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/ when this one is pending and it completes then the url is http://www.mdaccept.com/checkout/onepage/

And the response of http://www.mdaccept.com/checkout/onepage/ is the html of the checkout page.

Anyone knows this problem?

I hope my explanation is making sense :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by removing the `review` folder from my theme's `checkout` folder